# Enable template unit file?

Tags: systemd

As when adding @ symbol to unit file, it will become a template unit file. Can I do:

> sudo systemctl enable my-template@.service

? What will happen if I restarted the server? Would a new service get started using that template file? I need at least one service instance to start, but I am not familiar with template files best approach to solve this.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you restart the server yet to see what happened? Also, you may have better luck getting systemd questions answered on the Linux and Unix StackExchange site.

Answer (score 1):

Template units aren't meaningful on their own, as they should contain variables like %i where specific identifiers are filled in.

You would then use a command like:

```
systemctl enable my-template@some-instance
```

Exactly what this will be depends on what you have in your '[Instal]' section. See `man systemd.unit` for more about template units.